# Align button to input with float?

Tags: css

How can I align button right next to my input text. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ckfZE/)

HTML

```
<div id="frm">
<label>Select an Item:
    <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="..." class="open">
</label>

<label>Price:<input type="text" /></label>
```

CSS

```
#frm label
{ 
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding-right:6px;
}

#frm input
{
    display:block;

}
```

**Edit**
I want my form elements horizontally aligned in blocks & I like the popup button to align with just one textbox.
[image: Sample]

Comment: Remove all the CSS but `#frm label { padding-right:6px; }`. Problem solved.

Comment: I want to align my form elements horizontally as blocks. That is why the CSS is there for.

Comment: The html code looks ugly. Can you modify it?

Comment: @DamienJoe: So you use `inline-block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to move the `<input>` outside the `<label>`, like this:

```
<div id="frm">
    <div class="group">
        <label for="item">Select an Item:</label>
        <input type="text" id="item" />
        <input type="button" value="..." class="open">
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <label for="price">Price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="price" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to separate the inputs from the label, you should place the label text inside an own element, and not mix label text and input into a common tag.

Then, you can use the following CSS:

```
#frm .group {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

#frm label {
    display:block;
}
```

[See how it looks like](http://jsfiddle.net/cWgq5/), is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks so much Yogi. That is exactly what I want. Why are people saying my code is not good? Would you show me the 'correct' way to do this? I am just starting out with CSS so sorry about my broken code.

Comment: You put both literal text (*Select an Item:*) and html tags (`<input>`) into the label tag. This is not a good structure, because the input should exist beside the label, not as child of it. And the pratical reason is what I've mentioned: You want the label and the input look differently - so they should be different elements.

Comment: One thing more in your example if I have to use a new line after say 4 element blocks I have to use a p tag ? Like <p line1> div1 div2 div3</p> <p line 2> div1 div2 div3 <p>

Comment: The browser should wrap the group-divs automatically if they don't fit into one line. If you want to break after a given count of groups, add another class to the group-divs and then use the css `clear: both;` for them. But also test it with smaller browser windows!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ckfZE/18/

added a span-tag though

Comment: Uh, `<p>` inside `<label>`? That's against all conventions. Exchange them, and you've got nearly my code.

Comment: Can you give me a link of allowed conventions while designing webforms? I did not know my form was working in sort of ugly way.

Comment: Yogu is right, the p shouldn't be inside the label, use any other, a span for example

Answer (score 1):

-Easiest way to solve your problem, is to remove all CSS - `input` is inline by default, so it won't wrap to the next line if you add no CSS.

-And I'd add an extra div to make sure your fields are on seperate lines, no CSS needed either.

Like this:

```
<div id="frm">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Select an Item:</label>
        <input type="text"><input type="button" value="..." class="open">
    </div> 
    <div class="field">
        <label>Price:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ckfZE/15/

Comment: Hey that was cool but my requirement was to horizontally align in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS is causing that conflict:

```
#frm input {
    display:block;
}
```

You could set `.open` to `display:inline` to fix this.

Comment: I gave the solution to the problem he asked about. If necessary, I'll edit later with the full corrections.

Comment: Please advise me the recommended approach.

Answer (score -1):

Be a little more specific with your question.  If you took the CSS out completely they would be aligned right next to each other.  If you want them on separate lines add a `<br/>` after the   text input.