# How to align two Buttons to their respective Form Input?

Tags: html, css

Trying to figure out how to align some buttons to some input fields and it's tricky as hell. I couldn't figure it out.

[image]

I've found a lot of things online:
[Align button to input with float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602909/align-button-to-input-with-float)
[Align button with input forms with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878566/align-button-with-input-forms-with-labels)
[Make form button/text field same height in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483279/make-form-button-text-field-same-height-in-all-browsers)

I know I will get a lot of minuses but I just can't get my head around this and I need help.

I've lost a whole day modifying values and I have no clue on how to position things in CSS. I can't understand it.

```css
.big-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.box-head {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  border-bottom: 6px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.textbox {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.textbox input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 97%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

#button {
  display: grid;
  width: 25%;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"><img url="logo.png"></div>
<div class="big-box">
  <div class="box-head">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Configuration Page</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form method="post" action="/url" onSubmit="return saveValue();">
    <div class="textbox">
      <input type="url" placeholder="Enter URL" name="getURL" value="">
    </div>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Enter">
    <div class="textbox">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Brightness" name="getBrightness" value="">
    </div>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Enter">
  </form>
</div>
```

## EDIT: This is how I've fixed it:

- I've changed from class to ID: `#textbox`;
- I've put `#textbox` and `#button` inside div: `#box-box`;
- I've added `display: flex;` to `#box-box` and `display: grid;` to
  both `#textbox` and `#button`.
- Added `margin-left: 25px;` to `#button`;

Here is the [result](https://i.postimg.cc/CLvYyzYG/444.png).

Thanks @Flavio Caruso for the inspiration.

```
<body>
    <div id = "logo"><img url="logo.png"></div>
    <div class = "big-box">
        <div class = "box-head">
            <div class = "title"><h1>Configuration Page</h1></div>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="/url">
            <div id="box-box">
                <div id = "textbox" >
                    <input type="url" placeholder="Enter URL" name="getURL" value="">
                </div>
                <input id ="button" type="submit" value="Enter">
            </div>
            <div id="box-box">
                <div id = "textbox" >
                    <input type="url" placeholder="Enter URL" name="getURL" value="">
                </div>
                <input id ="button" type="submit" value="Enter">
            </div>
            <div id="box-box">
                <div id = "textbox" >
                    <input type="url" placeholder="Enter URL" name="getURL" value="">
                </div>
                <input id ="button" type="submit" value="Enter">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
#logo {
    width: 94%;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(logo.png) left no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

**#box-box {
    display:flex;
}**

#textbox {
    **display: grid;**
    width: 70%;    
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding 10px 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#textbox input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 97%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px;
}

#button {
    **display: grid;**
    width: 25%;
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid red;    
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 0;
    **margin-left: 25px;**
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a few changes you have to do, you must insert the input button inside the div class 'textbox' and add a display:flex, then you ajust the css from button to inline-block and float right.
like that:

```css
.big-box {    
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.box-head {    
    width: 100%;   
    display: grid;
    border-bottom: 6px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.textbox {
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.textbox input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 97%;
    margin: 5px 5px;
}

#button {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid red;    
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id = "logo"><img url="logo.png"></div>
    <div class = "big-box">
        <div class = "box-head">
            <div class = "title"><h1>Configuration Page</h1></div>
        </div>
        
        <form method="post" action="/url" onSubmit="return saveValue();">
            <div class = "textbox" >
                <input type="url" placeholder="Enter URL" name="getURL" value="">
            
            <input id ="button" type="submit" value="Enter">
            </div>
            <div class = "textbox" >
                <input type="number" placeholder="Brightness" name="getBrightness" value="">
                <input id ="button" type="submit" value="Enter"> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not really what I wanted. I want the buttons to be beside the input, not inside them.
This is what I got: [image](https://i.postimg.cc/L5DnjNjG/asdcx.png). You can see that the buttons are above the `border-bottom: 1px solid red;` of the `.textbox`. I want them to be beside them, on the right, not on top of them.
Thank you !

Comment: Adding ```display: inline-block;
    float: right;``` to the buttons does not change their place. So I don't think this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've modified the border of the `.textbox`: [image](https://i.postimg.cc/D0C6zQpP/333.png). You can clearly see that the buttons are inside `.textbox`. I want them out and on their right side.

Comment: I've made it work the way I want it. I've edited my original post, you check it out ! Thank you !

Comment: Sorry @ bleah1 I just read your comments now, but I saw that you did a great job!